# Theme custom css not work load MEDIA_URL

Tags: magento2, theme

I have 3 stores view and I would like each of them loads a custom CSS file.
I see that in **`content > design > configurations`** there is an entry for this (scripts and styles sheets) but when I put something like :

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}store/firstStore.css" />
```

It tries to load a CSS file from this URL https://mywebsite.develop/%7B%7BMEDIA_URL%7D%7Dstore/firstStore.css

Have you got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I did this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
        <block class="Vendor\Theme\Block\Head"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>


class Head extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $storeCode = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
        $storeCode = str_replace('_default', '', $storeCode);
        $this->pageConfig->addPageAsset('css/' . $storeCode . '.css');
        parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have different locale for each store than you can add custom css files ike that in app/design/frontend/yourtheme/web/

```
/web/i18n/de_DE/css/firststore_style.css
/web/i18n/en_US/css/Second_store_style.css
```

in your theme deafult_head_block.xml

```
        <css src="/web/i18n/de_DE/css/firststore_style.css" />
```

hope it helps

Comment: Yes but how i create a custom layout xml per store ? I found nothing on the web :/ If i put this on a block on the after body start then, the css will not be in the head

Comment: if you are using one theme for all stores then in your theme root directory in Magento_theme layout there you should have defeault_head_block.xml

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel, where you are trying to add CSS will not process the variable {{MEDIA_URL}} which you are using.

If you want to add the css file through admin then you need to give absolute URL of the css file like below.

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://ENTER_YOUR_SITE_HERE.COM/PATH_TO_CSS/store/firstStore.css" />
```

The ideal way would be to add through your theme layout.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Yes but with this way the css will no be in pub/static folder and expose to customers the real css paths isn't that good

Comment: Yes correct! but he was asking for how to add from admin so i mentioned this. Im presuming that he knows how to add it via theme layout.